# Aggregate nested documents with missing data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDB collection with data such as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "records" : [
        ISODate("2020-04-19T00:49:18.945Z"),
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId(""),
            "date" : ISODate("2020-05-07T04:49:55.643Z"),
            "text" : "someText"
        }
    ],
}
```

The value in `records` is different due to version upgrades.

I want to aggregate `records.text` across all documents ignoring the missing data. The code from [MongoDB: Aggregate and flatten an array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833926/mongodb-aggregate-and-flatten-an-array-field)

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind : "records"},
                      {$project: {_id: 1, 'text': '$records.text'}})
```

throws:

```
path option to $unwind stage should be prefixed with a '$': records
```

and fixing the error from [these directions](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20168) to accommodate empty fields:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind : "records", includeEmpty: false},
                      {$project: {_id: 1, 'text': '$records.text'}})
```

throws

```
A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.
```

How can I aggregate values from nested arrays with possibly empty values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the empty ones using [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$records" },
    { $match: { "records.text": { $exists: true } } },
    { $project: { _id: 1, text: "$records.text" }}
    {$group: {_id: "$text", count: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$sort: {count: -1}}
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b9lQKK9Nl69)

Answer (score 1):

In your first query, you are missing the '$', since record is a field value, so you should prefix it with '$'. The final query will be:

```js
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind : "$records"},
                      {$project: {_id: 1, 'text': '$records.text'}})
```

I hope this works for you.